# Writing a Log file in C/C++

Tags: c++, file, logging

I want to write a log file in C++. I am processing certain things and thus I need to maintain a log of the properties of the things that I process so that I could revert back to this log file to see the properties of anything that interests me in particular... Could someone help me in achieving this?

Comment: Are you referring to some kind of undo/redo system?

Comment: Have a look [at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696321/best-logging-framework-for-native-c)

Comment: @cyco130 I think the OP means "refer back to" rather than "revert back to", rather than some sort of undo/redo system. (The word "revert" possibly took over from spending too much time with git!)

Answer (score 57):

The standard method of logging (in my experience) is to use either the stdout or stderr streams. In C++ to use these you would need to include iostream, and use as below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  using std::cout;
  using std::cerr;
  using std::endl;

  cout << "Output message" << endl;
  cerr << "Error message" << endl;
}
```

This, however, only achieves printing to those outputs, which usually end up at a terminal. If you want to use these standard stream methods (which are quite readable) to output to a file, then you have to redirect your output somehow. One way of doing this is by using the `freopen` function, provided by cstdio. What this does is open a file, and moves a given stream to that file. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/freopen) for documentation. An example would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  using namespace std;
  freopen( "output.txt", "w", stdout );
  freopen( "error.txt", "w", stderr );

  cout << "Output message" << endl;
  cerr << "Error message" << endl;
}
```

(I've changed to `using namespace std;` there just for conciseness.)

You're moving the standard output stream `stdout` (which is used by `cout`) to output.txt (in write mode), and you're moving `stderr` (which is used by `cerr`) to error.txt also in write mode.

Hopefully this does the trick.

Comment: I would recommend std::clog over std::cout and std::cerr.

Comment: I'd actually never heard of clog before you mentioned it. I can see why a buffered version of stderr might be useful - but why use it in place of cout? What's wrong with both?

Comment: Technically?  Nothing.  But that's the standard way to do normal logging.  Just like cerr should be used for error logging, and cout for console output.  
And honestly?  I only heard about it a week ago.

Comment: Is there an option to redirect `std::clog` and `std::cerr` into separate files , because both seem to write to the sample location. Something like `freopen( "log.txt", "w", stdlog );` ?

Comment: Is it possible to keep both? Redirect to log file *and* output to console?

Comment: `freopen` is not safe, you should use `freopen_s` like that:   ```FILE *stream;
 errno_t err;
 err = freopen_s(&stream, "freopen.out", "w", stdout);  if (err != 0) {
 exit(1);
    }```  read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/freopen-s-wfreopen-s?view=msvc-160#example

Comment: does this function append new line to source txt?

Comment: you need close man. `fclose(stdout);`

Answer (score 33):

This is quite handy; just plug into, e.g., some common header file to be called from anywhere in the program (a better approach would be to form a class with these functions)

```
inline string getCurrentDateTime( string s ){
    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm  tstruct;
    char  buf[80];
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);
    if(s=="now")
        strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d %X", &tstruct);
    else if(s=="date")
        strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d", &tstruct);
    return string(buf);
};
inline void Logger( string logMsg ){

    string filePath = "/somedir/log_"+getCurrentDateTime("date")+".txt";
    string now = getCurrentDateTime("now");
    ofstream ofs(filePath.c_str(), std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app );
    ofs << now << '\t' << logMsg << '\n';
    ofs.close();
}
```

Usage: `Logger("This is log message");`
Writes a file (or appends existing file)

```
/somedir/log_2017-10-20.txt
```

with content:

```
2017-10-20 09:50:59 This is log message
```

Answer (score 5):

The sort of thing you're trying to do is too in-depth to provide a complete solution on stack overflow. What you can do is check out the documentation for the logging library of your choice. In my case, that's `Boost.Log`, a logging library for the [Boost C++ libraries](http://www.boost.org/) the documentation for which can be found [here](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/index.html).

It's pointed out at the bottom of the page I've just linked to that

> This library is not an official part of Boost libraries collection
>   although it has passed the review and is provisionally accepted. The
>   review result is available [here](http://lists.boost.org/boost-announce/2010/03/0256.php).

so make of that what you will.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use one of the many logging frameworks available, like [Apache log4cxx](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/index.html)? I would suggest this rather than attempting to roll your own - why re-invent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

You also might want to consider https://github.com/johnwbyrd/logog .  It's a performance-oriented C++ logging system.  However, if that's a little too intense for your project, good old cerr and cout work fine for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<string>
#include <fstream>

inline std::string getCurrentDateTime( std::string s ){
    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm  tstruct;
    char  buf[80];
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);
    if(s=="now")
        strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d %X", &tstruct);
    else if(s=="date")
        strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d", &tstruct);
    return  std::string(buf);
};

inline void Logger(std::string logMsg){
    std::string filePath = "./log_"+getCurrentDateTime("date")+".txt";
    std::string now = getCurrentDateTime("now");
    std::ofstream ofs(filePath.c_str(), std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app );
    ofs << now << '\t' << logMsg << '\n';
    ofs.close();
}
```

For example:

```
Logger("JAMLEE: ---------| start VT_SETMODE");
```