# How can I configure Codeblocks to not close the console after the program has finished?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, console, codeblocks

I should specify, I **do not** want to do the waiting for input thing or to use the debugger. I want the program to run and terminate as it normally would, but where the console window doesn't close after termination. I know it can be done, I've seen people with hello world programs (without `getchar()`) press 'build and run' and the window remains open.

I use Code::Blocks 17.12 on Windows 10.

Comment: The behaviour of Code::Blocks varies between versions and platforms. Maybe specify the version number and the operating system you are using? On my current computer (Debian, codeblocks 16), it just works out of the box.

Comment: @user12986714 I've edited my post to include this information.

Comment: This may be a duplicate, see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040466/why-does-my-codeblock-only-display-output-for-less-than-second) helps you

Comment: @metablaster Visual Studio has problems too. It's a multi-Gigabyte monster with intransparent data collection (which is putting it very mildly) practices, which only supports Windows, which again has at least the latter problem, too, especially 10.

Comment: @nada lack of disk space (or even memory space) is no excuse these days when these computer components are not expensive, it's not 1980 when you had to work on 1GB memory or 50GB HDD. beside the OP is using Windows 10. and those data collections can be disabled.

Comment: @metablaster I'm sorry, but i have to disagree. Abundance of resources does not justify wasting them. And disabling data collection is not as easy as you make it sound. There even exist things like _Windows 10 decrapifiers_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Project -> Properties -> Build targets`. You should see a checkbox labeled: `Pause when execution ends` somewhere there. Your application type must be `Console application`.

Note: I use Code::Blocks 16.01. Yours may vary slightly.

Alternatively, you can log to a file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE* logfile;

int main() {
    logfile = fopen("logging.txt", "w");
    if(logfile == NULL) {
        // Couldn't open the file.
        return 1;
    }

    fprintf(logfile, "Logging to logging.txt\n");

    fclose(logfile);

    return 0;
}
```

Or you can 'redirect' `stdout` to a file:

```
freopen("stdout.txt", "w", stdout);
printf("Logging to stdout.txt\n");
```

Both of those are C. For C++: [Writing a Log file in c/c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400418/writing-a-log-file-in-c-c)